# broke sql server VIEW, need to rollback

Tags: sql-server-2008, rollback

I did an `ALTER VIEW` command and it broke my view.
I want to ROLLBACK but don't know how to do this in `SQL Server`.

Should I just close management studio and not save anything.

Would this fix it and rollback by itself, or does it `COMMIT` automatically every time I click `EXECUTE`?

Comment: By default, SQL Server runs in Autocommit mode. Unless you've taken steps to change it, that's what mode your session was running in.

Comment: if you have backup(s) you can restore your view, or CTRL+Z in SSMS if still have the screen open and re-execute ALTER with the unmodified VIEW. Otherwise you should post a new question on SO asking how to create a view which displays this and that data in the format you like (i.e. ask the community to help you restore the original view).